# Ember Rails Authentication with Devise and a non-single-page app

Tags: authentication, ember.js, devise, ember-rails

I have an existing extensive rails app where I am wanting to change one of the (rails) views to be more dynamic and hence integrating an Ember App at this route.

Without authentication this works nicely. It's easy to navigate around the existing rails app and the user can navigate to the main path the ember app is on, play around in there and then following other links end up back out in standard rails views. Adding authentication though is causing pain.

1. Is it possible to have a user login to devise session via rails and then when the user visits an ember route then ember checks that a current (rails) user is present?
2. What specifically is needed to allow the user to also post updates from within Ember back to the rails model in an authenticated way.

I'm currently using the ember-rails gem and went with implementing https://github.com/d-i/ember-devise-simple-auth as it was the best solution I could find that supported ember-rails.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find this helpful: [Playing with Ember.js  and Devise](http://pivotallabs.com/playing-with-ember-js-and-devise/)

I am interested in using Ember in a similar way, so if you get anywhere I'd really appreciate if you post your solution here.

Comment: I did not find a suitable solution and ended up giving up on incorporating Ember into my app for now. Sorry to disappoint...